# Two activities on android: error force close 

Tags: android

I want to make two intent `Activity`s in android, the first one being

```
    txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);   

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(yaraby.this, HelloItemizedOverlay.class);
            yaraby.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

and the second one

```
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Mapy.this, yaraby.class);
        Mapy.this.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Is this right to open two activities?

So the error when I run it the first intent open when I click next to open second intent it force close and on the cat log

```
05-21 01:00:23.913: VERBOSE/AudioFlinger(95): MixerThread 0xbb50 TID 152 waking up
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: yaraby.y.HelloItemizedOverlay
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212):     at yaraby.y.yaraby$1.onClick(yaraby.java:48)
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212):     at  android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-21 01:00:23.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9212):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />    

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".yaraby"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity android:name=".Mapy"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity android:name=".HelloItemizedOverlay"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
   package yaraby.y;

                import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
     import java.net.Socket;

                 import android.app.Activity;
                    import android.content.Intent;
                                  import android.os.Bundle;
                                  import android.view.Vieimport                                                           android.view.View.OnClickListener;
          import android.widget.Button;
                                               import android.widget.EditText;
                                           import android.widget.TextView;
                                                                                                  v          import android.widget.Toast;
```

mapy import

```
package yaraby.y;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.DatagramPacket;
 import java.net.DatagramSocket;
   import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
 import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.SocketException;
      import java.util.List;
                                            ///and other 




           public class Mapy extends MapActivity

                        {


 05-21 03:40:37.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  05-21 03:40:37.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12691): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: yaraby.y.Mapy
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you want to know how to open an activity, or how to be able to open two different activites from within a third activity?

Comment: Have you added the activity `HelloItemizedOverlay` to your manifest?

Comment: yaraby.class should be Yaraby.class (capital Y) ?

Comment: Why it should be Y capital @ martin

Comment: here its is added in the mainfest  .
HelloItemizedOverlay is a class  to add items in the map

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells you that it cannot find the class yaraby.y.HelloItemizedOverlay.
Does it exist?
Is it the right package?
Have you imported it?
Is it visible and accessible?
Have you imported a class with the same name from a different package?

Comment: HelloItemizedOverlay is a class on depend on the mapy activity

Comment: In all your code I still can't find any declaration of HelloItemizedOverlay.

Answer (score 0):

First ; verify your import of your classes, 
Second : if you have your activities in different packages , you should define them on your minfest like this :

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".yaraby"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="mapyPackageName.Mapy"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="HelloItemPackageName.HelloItemizedOverlay"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Third : 
 try to add this to your manifest in the element *application* :

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

follow this link , it will help you :)===>  [your happyness](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

Comment: No they all in same package  and i will upload my imports now

Comment: i think that the error is something wrong in your manifest , 

see my edit

Comment: i add the library before the activities

Comment: 05-21 03:40:37.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 03:40:37.703: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12691): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: yaraby.y.Mapy